# Remove external library from reference lookup in SandCastle

Tags: sandcastle

I have a project that uses MVC and NHibernate. I don't want to add documentation for these libraries when building the documentation for my project. The problem is that deriving from a class in these libraries gives a lot of warnings and makes it difficult to see more serious warnings (like missing documentation, wrong links etc).

I have already disabled warning 1591 for parts of my code, but this doesn't help. I've removed `Inherited base class members` from `Visibility` in the config, but this doesn't help.

Is there a way I can remove lookup of these components?

The actual errors looks like this

> C:\Program Files (x86)\EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File Builder\SandcastleHelpFileBuilder.targets(40,3): warning : BuildAssembler : warning : ResolveReferenceLinksComponent: [M:MYSESSIONFACTORY.Close] Unknown reference link target 'M:NHibernate.ISessionFactory.Close'. [C:\PROJECTPATH\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME.Documentation\Help\Working\BuildReferenceTopics.proj]

Comment: I had a similar problem documenting a custom log4net appender, where I was getting unwanted warnings about unknown references to log4net targets.  The solution was to add the Additional References plug-in to the main SHFB project as described in the last answer to this thread: https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/issues/67